# Multiple IRS Levy Notices?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

My wife received a Notice of levy in Dec. 2019. We had no issues with this, as we did owe. The amount of the levy has since been met, but the levy is still in effect. We file jointly, so both of our SSNs are on the levy.

To make it even more confounding, I just received a notice of levy from *my* employer for the same amount and the same year.

Due to the coronavirus epidemic, the IRS offices are closed. The phone lines are too congested to reach anyone. I can't even get through to a Tax Advocate.

Is there someone, anyone I can contact to get a response?